# Implement funcaptcha in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to implement a FunCaptcha in asp.net mvc application.
I can implement simple captcha, but I don't know about funcaptcha.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Link to funcaptcha : https://octocaptcha.com/